# How to Determine StrokeThickness of Application Bar

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am having trouble determining the application bar button StrokeThickness. I've come as far as either it being 3 or 4 but I need to know the exact value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recreate the circle used in the application bar buttons you'll find a copy at

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Icons\Dark\basecircle.png"